# How to make decorator work with async function?

Tags: python, api, async-await, python-asyncio

Generic question:

I have a decorator `@some_package.decorator` that expects the function to wrap to return type `T`.

```py
### runs
@some_package.decorator
def my_func(param) -> int:
    return len(param)

### I also want to be able to wrap an async function
@some_package.decorator
async def my_func(param):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return len(param)
```

However the function can either be `sync` or `async` and so may return `coroutine[Any]`.

How can I make the decorator `await` the function

My specific use case:
I have some code that works well when `sync=True`

```py
import uplink
class MyAPI(Consumer):
        def __init__(
        self,
        password: str,
        sync: bool = True,
        auto_auth: bool = True,
        **kwargs
    ):
        self.sync = sync
        self.client = None

        if not self.sync:
            self.client = AiohttpClient()

        # initialise the super class
        super(GLinet, self).__init__(client=self.client, **kwargs)

        if auto_auth:
                self._login(password)

    @uplink.returns.json(key="token")
    @uplink.post("router/login")
    def _login(self, pwd: uplink.Field):
        """fetches token"""
```

However when `sync=False` the API I am using makes and _login() and async function. As such the decorator `uplink.returns.json` becomes upset as it expects the function it wraps to prove a response that is can parse but instead it receives a co routine.

How can I make the `uplink.returns.json` accept an async function and await a return value that it can parse.

I tried something like this

```py
def dec(fn):
    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(fn):
        @returns.json
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("wrapping async function")
            print(fn)
            return await fn()
        return wrapper
    else:
        @returns.json
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("wrapping sync function")
            print(fn)
            return fn()
        return wrapper
```

Some people have developed their own decorators that can take both tpyes of functions, but I haven't found anyone who has modified another decorator

```py
def dec(fn):
    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(fn, args, kwargs)  # <function foo at 0x10952d598> () {}
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            print("done with wrapper, going to call fn")
            return await fn()
        return wrapper
    else:
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(fn, args, kwargs)  # <function bar at 0x108fb5a60> () {}
            time.sleep(5)
            print("done with wrapper, going to call fn")
            return fn()
        return wrapper
```

Comment: it is an example of someone creating a purpose built decorator that does this - but not a method of modifying a pre-existing decorator to do so